# Prevent duplicate entries in database during POST call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I have an API written in Asp Net Core 2.1 (upgraded from 2.0) which build an entity from a DTO sent by a mobile app.
The DTO have a field "mobileId" (Guid format) to prevent the mobile to send the same object when it goes online (after connectivity issues for example).

But this solution does not seem to be efficient as presented below :

[image: Database]

There are 4 lines whereas I actually wanted only 1 line :S I don't understand how it occurred because I specified in the Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext>(s =>
{
    // code emitted for brevity
});
```

The code of the API itself is centralized in a Handler because our API follow a little piece of CQRS pattern and the "Dispatcher" is registered via Autofac :

```
public class DispatcherModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Dispatcher>()
            .As<IDispatcher>()
            .InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

The same applies for IUnitOfWork which use our scoped DbContext internally

At the beginning I check that an entity with the same 'mobileId' is not already present in database :

```
if (dto.MobileId != null)
{
    Report existingMobileId = await UnitOfWork.Repository<Report>()
                    .GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(qr => qr.MobileId == dto.MobileId);
    if (existingMobileId != null)
    {
        return new Result<object>(new Error(400, $"Report with '{dto.MobileId}' already exists in DB."));
    }
}
```

What do you think I'm doing wrong ? Or maybe I should add something else ?
Thank you for your help guyz :)

Technical environment :
- ASP.NET Core 2.1
- Entity Framework Core
- Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddScoped means that new instance of service is created for each request, so, if you have several simultaneous requests, you may have some kind of race condition on repository level when each checks presence of a row before writing it to db. I would recommend putting this responsibility on the database level applying Unique constraint on mobileId column.